# CircleCI build on PR

Tags: circleci

I have a CircleCI integration in an open-source project, and I would like to build PRs automatically, as shown in their github integration page:

[image: CircleCI integration]

(Step 5, "Your tests passed on CircleCI")

For instance, this PR did not display it: https://github.com/nha/boot-uglify/pull/2 and was not built on the feature branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there is an option in Advanced Settings > Build off PRs

[image: CircleCI build PRs]